# Transfer files at intervals

Tags: c, unix, client-server

I'm writing a client/server C application where i would transfer files ,at intervals of programmed time,from client to the server. How can I do? There are some functions to do this? Should I use the threads?

Comment: I have no idea how can i do

Answer (score 2):

```
'cron' could fire a shell script, 
the shell script would use fpt or tftp 
and some file that lists which files to transfer, 
for the actual file transfer
```

Comment: Every client have a working directory and I would that all files in it are transferred to the server

Answer (score 1):

You can have the sender `sleep` in a loop, so that the sender only wakes-up, checks for files to send, sends 1 file, then goes back to sleep.

`#include <unistd.h>
unsigned int sleep(unsigned int seconds);`

Comment: This would put on hold the process. Should I create a thread to handle this?